# Django template tags security issue

Tags: django, security

I have an application which generates reports based on data of the MySQL database. Since customers want to use this report application as well and don't want to use our crappy report styles but their own styles, I want to implement a feature which lets them upload their own styles with HTML, CSS and Javascript. Since they obviously need their dynamic content in their reports they have to use Django template tags. Is there any security issue with letting customers, use every Django template tag or should I implement some kind of "markdown syntax" for specific django template tags that users are allowed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't need to use django template tags at all, you need to provide them a html template that they can override with their own css styling.

You then store their preferences in either a `FileField` or a large `charfield` that you then reference in your templates to load their styling where needed.

i.e

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ user.styling.stylesheet }}" type="text/css" />
  <style>{{ user.styling.css }}</style>
```

Comment: @IbrahimApachi - Just be aware that the second one can have its own security issues if they start their field with `</style><script>evil code</script><style>` but then if a customer is dumb enough to poison themselves its their own fault

Comment: But Javascript code wont be executed when in style tags, am I right?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi - Thats my point, they've closed the style tag, opened a script tag, then opened a new one to complete it, result in two empty style tags and a script. But then it looks like you want them to introduce their own js anyway :)

Comment: But if I wanted them to not include javascript code I just should check for closing or opening script or/and style tags, if I am not mistaken

Comment: @IbrahimApachi - Yes that would be a start, at least the end tag. Or choose to let them upload a file